# How to get the Old value of a lead status

Tags: leads

Do we have an option to get the old value of a lead status and update the same value?

I tried out using the Lead history option .But the issue is in the lead status picklist value we have different values which are dependent on the other.so can we track even does values ,because those fields are mandatory.

For Example:

In lead Status --the old value was as "Reengage" and got changed to new value as "Item Updated".So lead history it shows the value of old and new.But when the value was "Reengage" ,it was interlinked with other two fields ,so i would like to retrieve those values also.

Do we have an option.How to get it.There are nearly 4k records which got updated and would like to retrieve their values.
Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add more info on the Object, field name and type of interlink you have and Is History tracking not so useful in your case ?

Comment: @karthikselva :Thanks for your response.On lead object ,we have a lead status with different picklist value and reenage is on of the value.This Reengage has two dependent fields as reengage frame work and reengage reason.In lead Status --the old value was as "Reengage" and got changed to new value as "Item Updated".Now i would like to update the old value as Reengege in lead status when i try doing it manually the two dependent fields are mandatory field and im unable to change the value.how achieve it.Any suggestion plz.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question significantly depends on your edition as well as how and where you want to see that information:

1. a report
2. a visual force page (e.g. for use in a page-layout)
3. a query in the console (since you're an admin)
4. an export (via DataLoader) — if it's more of a one-time operation

For the future, consider [Reporting Snapshots](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_about_analytic_snap.htm) that  you need to define prior to any subsequent reporting on historical data (or in this case snapshots thereof).

**Addendum**

Based on your comment:

> I wanted to Update the Lead Owner Using The dataloader. But Instead of updating the Owner the lead status got changed. Now i would like to get the lead status of previous one.

First of all, that is the most crucial information your OP would highly benefit from mentioning.

To me, it sounds like 4. above is the way to go, so you:

1. export your lead history data using dataloader
2. filter out those changed in a given time frame
3. set those records back to their previous value using dataloader

Comment: :Thanks for your reply.I wanted to Update the Lead Owner Using The dataloader .But Instead of updating the Owner the lead status got changed.Now i would like to get the lead status of previous one.

Comment: Hi @SalesforceCRMAccountCRM, I added an addendum to my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: :On lead object ,we have a lead status with different picklist value and reenage is on of the value.This Reengage has two dependent fields as reengage frame work and reengage reason.In lead Status --the old value was as "Reengage" and got changed to new value as "Item Updated".Now i would like to update the old value as Reengege in lead status when i try doing it manually the two dependent fields are mandatory field and im unable to change the value.These two fields doesnot have the track history checked nd unable to find the value of them .Any suggestion plz.

Comment: @SalesforceCRMAccountCRM, Sorry to say but I think you're out of luck with this. Without history tracking I don't see a way for you to get back to the previous state for these fields, unless you have some old exports / reports lying around.

Your best bet is to make a report of all the affected leads and discuss a strategy as to what to do about them with your mgt.